# Raspberry pi Zero W reboot after USB is disconnected/connected

Tags: pi-zero-w, power-supply, display, usb-power, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am using raspberry pi 3b+ and Zero W and a Waveshare 7 inch capacitive touch display.

I am trying to turn off the back light of the display in various following ways in both the Pis. So if the turn the display ON it should stay in the current page.

- turning off the sliding switch behind the display
- taking off the Usb cable directly from the port
- using the command "echo '1-1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind"

When in 3B+ everything works fine if I turn the display ON.

But ..,

In zero W , doing the first two options, when I turned the display on after few minutes it RESTARTS. where as in command, the screen just freezes( only the touch is disable but power is there).

What might be the reason for why it particularly restarts ?